# C# Dynamic Linq Query Multiple OR Logic

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm not a C# programmer, nor did I design the database for this, but I've been tasked with creating a Linq query that doesn't know what columns to use at compile time. Trying to be succinct, here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:

From the frontend, the user can select one or more groups and expect back a JSON string containing those users that will fill up a paginated table.

Let's say I have these groups:

Group1

Group2

Group3

Group4

and the user selects Group1, Group2, and Group4. They expect back from the database users that belong to any one of these groups.

In the database, these group names are column names.

If I were to write a straight SQL statement it would look something like this:

```
SELECT EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName
FROM Contacts AS C
JOIN GroupContacts AS D
ON C.ID = D.ContactId
WHERE D.DealId = 'some unique id'
AND (
        D.Group1 = 1
        OR
        D.Group2 = 1
        OR
        D.Group4 = 1
    )
ORDER BY C.LastName
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Where the  = 1 means that Contact is in that group.

All I want to be able to do is to make that AND (...) part dynamic, depending on what the user has selected.

I've investigated how to do it with C# Expressions, but the functions I'm coming across (Expression.OrElse()) can only take two parameters.

What is my approach here?

EDIT:

Here is my sad C# code:

```
String[] GroupNames = { "Group1", "Group2", "Group4" }; // user selected groups
List<Expression> expressionList = new List<Expression>();

foreach (String name in GroupNames)
{
    expressionList.Add(Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(name), 1));
}
```

Here is where I'm really not sure what to do. I think I could write the rest of the expression if I could just get this expressionList to evaluate.

I know that I will have a finite number of groups. At first I tried writing a switch statement sort of solution:

```
List<Expression> expressionList = new List<Expression>();
Expression expressionOR = Expression.Empty();
Expression rightSide = Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool));

foreach (string name in GroupNames)
{
    switch (name)
    {
        case "Group1":
            leftSide = Expression.Constant("Group1");
            e1 = Expression.Equal(leftSide, rightSide);
            break;

        case "Group2":
            leftSide = Expression.Constant("Group2");
            e2 = Expression.Equal(leftSide, rightSide);
            break;

        case "Group3":
            leftSide = Expression.Constant("Group3");
            e3 = Expression.Equal(leftSide, rightSide);
            break;

        case "Group4":
            leftSide = Expression.Constant("Group4");
            e4 = Expression.Equal(leftSide, rightSide);
            break;
    }

    expressionOR = Expression.Equal(leftSide, rightSide);
    expressionList.Add(expressionOR);
}
```

And then I would try to use Expression.OrElse(expressionList); is some way.

Forgive my naivety on C#, and thanks so far to everybody who has responded. It's really appreciated.

Comment: *Expression.OrElse() can only take two parameters*. What you are missing is that parameters are also expressions, hence could be another `OrElse` expression.

Comment: Show what you have so far.  It's likely you can add conditions like `group1Selected && D.Group1 == 1` but without some C# code an exact solution is difficult.

Comment: Speaking about expressions. [this predicate builder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) might help.

Comment: Do you use expressions in other places or are you just trying to use it here  to dynamically add other conditions?

Comment: Just here D Stanley, my first stab at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't post a lot of code to go on but if you're just trying to use expressions to dynamically add conditions you don't need to.  You could do something like:

```
where DealId == "some unique id" 
   && ((GroupNames.Contains("Group1") && Group1 = 1) || 
       (GroupNames.Contains("Group2") && Group2 = 1) || 
       (GroupNames.Contains("Group3") && Group3 = 1) || 
       (GroupNames.Contains("Group4") && Group4 = 1))
```

Comment: I'm going to try this out. If it's as simple as this I'll be happy to have the task done, but embarrassed I missed something.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks for showing me the problem was not nearly as complicated as I thought!

Answer (score 0):

Need using System.Linq.Dynamic [NuGet relation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)

Sample:

```
var gropString = String.Format("new ({0})", GroupDocumentByFields().ToSeparatedString());
var groupping = list1.AsQueryable().GroupBy(gropString, "it");
foreach (IGrouping<dynamic, ITAP.Database.OrderItems> items in groupping) {
     var idorders = items.Select(p => p.IDOrder).Distinct().ToList();
     var goods = listGoods.Where(p => idorders.Contains(p.IDOrder));
     var services = listServices.Where(p => idorders.Contains(p.IDOrder));
```

...

```
 protected List<string> GroupDocumentItemsByFields() {
        var fields = new List<string>();
        if (GetNameVariant == Selling.GetNameVariant.OrderItemsName)
            fields.Add("Name as ItemName");
        if (GetNameVariant == Selling.GetNameVariant.OrderItemsShortName)
            fields.Add("ShortName as ItemName");
        if (GetNameVariant == Selling.GetNameVariant.SellingName)
            fields.Add("SellingName as ItemName");

        if(this.PriceVariant == Selling.PriceVariant.PriceWithoutNDS)
            fields.Add("PriceWithoutNDS as Price");
        if (this.PriceVariant == Selling.PriceVariant.Price)
            fields.Add("Price as Price");

        return fields;            
    }
```

Comment: I considered this and think it will definitely work. But, it's not necessary for my problem. In the future, this would be a good library to use for truly more complex problems.